# When i run the following code adding str.front() + str.back it gives me 200 but why?

Tags: c++, string

```
string str = "abcdefg"; 
cout << str.back() + str.front();
```

C++ console: 
200

Comment: `200` is surely the sum of the decimal values of `a` & `g` with whatever character set you're using. [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) appears to fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str = "abcdefg";
    for(int v : str) {
        std::cout << v << " " << static_cast<char>(v) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Possible output:

```
97 a    // front()
98 b
99 c
100 d
101 e
102 f
103 g   // back()
```

97+103 = 200

Comment: Thank you Ted for you responce!

Answer (score 0):

> When i run the following code adding str.front() + str.back it gives me 200 but why?

Characters are encoded as integers. `char` is an integer type. When operands of an arithmetic operation (such as addition) are integer types smaller than `int`, those operands are promoted to `int`, which is also the result type of the expression. That is why the output is not an encoded character, but decimal representation of the integer instead.

Why the value 200, well it just so happens that in the character encoding of your system, the value that represents `'a'` and the value that represents `'g'` total 200 when added together.

Comment: Worth to mention the range of `signed char` values, and this will trigger the promotion to `int`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Characters of string literal are `char`, not `signed char` (which is a different type), and the promotion of the operands happens regardless of their signedness and range of representable values.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

You're adding two `char`s, which results in an integer.

If you want to combine the two characters to a string, you have to give at least one of them string type, e.g. :

```
cout << str.back() + string{str.front()};
```

or

```
cout << str.back() + str.substr(0, 1);
```

---

If you just want to output two characters, though - you can simply output them one at a time:

```
cout << str.back() << str.front();
```

Comment: Or, use `operator<<` instead of `operator+`: `cout << str.back() << str.front();`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, That's nowhere near complicated enough.  ;o)

Comment: not everything in C++ has to be complicated. Some things are actually designed to make life easier.